# What can I do to optimize this SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a query like this that runs on a site:

```
SELECT *
FROM `orders`
WHERE
    `co_id`='12660' &&
    ((`from_region`=6 && `to_region`=60) || `id` IN('539110')) &&
    (
        `p_name` LIKE '%search%' ||
        `p_street_address` LIKE '%search%' ||
        `p_city` LIKE '%search%' ||
        `p_state` LIKE '%search%' ||
        `p_zip` LIKE '%search%' ||
        `p_non_us_address` LIKE '%search%' ||
        `p_contact` LIKE '%search%'
    ) &&
    (
        (`when_deleted` >= 1349222400 && `when_deleted` <= 1378511999) ||
        (`assigned_to_date` >= 1349222400 && `assigned_to_date` <= 1378511999) ||
        (`deleted` = "0" && `assigned_to` = "")
    )
ORDER BY p_state,p_city,p_zip,date_time DESC LIMIT 20,20;
```

It's a search query that searches for text across quite a few columns.  The table holds orders and the query only checks for orders in certain regions and that it was between certain dates (either that it was deleted or assigned during that time, or that it's still outstanding) as well as searching for the text.

The table itself looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `orders` (
  `co_id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `from_region` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `to_region` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `when_deleted` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `important` smallint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `p_street_address` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `p_city` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `p_state` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `p_zip` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `p_non_us_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `p_country` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `p_residence` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `p_contact` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `p_phone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `p_cell` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `p_altphone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `p_fax` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `p_email` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `p_addl_info_1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `p_addl_info_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `vehs_avail` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `d_street_address` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `d_city` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `d_state` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `d_zip` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `d_non_us_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `d_country` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `d_residence` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `d_contact` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `d_phone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `d_cell` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `d_altphone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `d_fax` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `d_email` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `d_addl_info_1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `d_addl_info_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `deliver_by` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `b_CustomerId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `b_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `b_street_address` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `b_city` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `b_state` char(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `b_zip` varchar(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `b_non_us_address` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `b_country` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `b_contact` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `b_phone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `b_cell` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `b_altphone` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `b_fax` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `b_email` varchar(80) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `b_addl_info_1` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `b_addl_info_2` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `num_units` decimal(5,2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `price_per_unit` decimal(9,2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `price_per_load` decimal(9,2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `additional_charge` decimal(9,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `additional_charge_desc` text NOT NULL,
  `fuelSurchargePercent` float(5,2) NOT NULL,
  `fuelSurchargeAmt` decimal(9,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `poNumber` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `cod` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `run_drive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `desc_vehs` text NOT NULL,
  `other_notes` text NOT NULL,
  `assigned_to` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `assigned_to_date` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `assignedOn` datetime NOT NULL,
  `loaded` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `delivered` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notifications_entered` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notifications_assigned` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notifications_loaded` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notifications_delivered` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `notifications_email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `owner` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date_time` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `changed` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `synced` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`co_id`,`id`),
  KEY `from_region` (`from_region`),
  KEY `to_region` (`to_region`),
  KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  KEY `Delivered` (`delivered`),
  KEY `owner` (`owner`),
  KEY `b_CustomerId` (`b_CustomerId`),
  KEY `co_id` (`co_id`),
  KEY `co_id-p_name` (`co_id`,`p_name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

I know that I could create some additional indexes on p_name, p_street_address, p_city, p_state, p_zip, p_non_us_address, and p_contact, but that's just searching for the pickup location.  There's also a delivery and billing location that can be searched.  By the time I add indexes to all those inserts are going to be drastically slower.  Is there possibly a better way that I could structure this query to improve it's efficiency?  Separate queries? Sub queries?  Maybe there's even a way to create a separate table that's just for searches?

Comment: I think you should consider a re design of your database and split the one table into several ones. What is when one customer has more than one delivery adress?

Answer (score 0):

Generally seeing things like `%search%` mean the query *can't* be optimized. MySQL's built in indexing feature works very well for things like `search%` where it can look that up quickly. Anything with a wildcard at the front means it will have to test against every single record individually, which can be extremely slow.

If you want to do full-text search, you should probably use the `FULLTEXT` index type. This has worked on the dangerously flaky MyISAM table type for years now, but MySQL 5.6 includes support for this on InnoDB.

A full-text index on those columns would help massively, but you'll need to use the full-text searching `MATCH` command instead of `LIKE`.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding these indexes:

```
ALTER TABLE `orders` ADD FULLTEXT p_fulltext_idx (`p_name`,`p_street_address`,`p_city`,`p_state`,`p_zip`,`p_non_us_address`,`p_contact`);
ALTER TABLE `orders` ADD FULLTEXT d_fulltext_idx (`d_name`,`d_street_address`,`d_city`,`d_state`,`d_zip`,`d_non_us_address`,`d_contact`);
ALTER TABLE `orders` ADD FULLTEXT b_fulltext_idx (`b_name`,`b_street_address`,`b_city`,`b_state`,`b_zip`,`b_non_us_address`,`b_contact`);
```

I also changed the query to use:

```
MATCH(`p_name`, `p_street_address`, `p_city`, `p_state`, `p_zip`, `p_non_us_address`, `p_contact`) AGAINST('search')
```

I'm waiting to see how this affects writes before it goes live, but the searches are WAY faster.  I'll try to remember to post back here once it's all rolled out.